# When are SQL Server Index Usage Stats Updated?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, indexing

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2, and running the following query to try and see when an index was last updated in my database using the following SQL:

```
SELECT last_system_update, last_user_update,
OBJECT_NAME(object_id) AS tblName
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE database_id = DB_ID('mydatabase')
```

The **last_user_update** field is correct, and contains NULL where no updates have been made to the table since the last restart of SQL Server.

When I run the following query to rebuild the index, I'd expect the **last_system_update** field to contain a date to indicate the index was rebuilt:

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON dbo.MyTable
REBUILD
```

However this field remains NULL. In fact the last_system_update field is empty (NULL) for all indexes in all the databases on the server. **last_user_update** does not change either.

I also tried:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.MyTable
```

But no luck. So when is this field updated? And how can I force it to be updated?

Comment: I havent checked it but i was under the impression that sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats was updated every time the query is used (user_updates) in a query; i don't think that a reindex would count under the rules. You could write a query that selects and use a query hint to touch the index.

Comment: Thanks u07ch. The stats for last_user_scan/seek are fine. I'm trying to get the last time the index was rebuilt/modified - but not by editing the table.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the following query to determine when the Indexes were last updated, which uses [`STATS_DATE()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190330.aspx):

```
USE your_db;
SELECT t.name AS Table_Name
      ,i.name AS Index_Name
      ,i.type_desc AS Index_Type
      ,STATS_DATE(i.object_id,i.index_id) AS Date_Updated
FROM sys.indexes i
JOIN sys.tables t
  ON t.object_id = i.object_id
WHERE i.type > 0 
ORDER BY t.name ASC
    ,i.type_desc ASC
    ,i.name ASC;
```

I believe this will only work with SQL Server 2005 or newer, since sys.indexes was not in SQL Server 2000.

Answer (score 0):

I found some  more details on these columns at:

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/louis_davidson/archive/2007/07/22/sys-dm-db-index-usage-stats.aspx

> system_seeks, system_scans, system_lookups, system_updates,
> last_system_seek, last_system_scan, last_system_lookup,
> last_system_update
>
> Same as the user query columns, but records when
> the index is used for a system operation, such as automatic statistics
> operations.